# Does every method in Ruby return a value?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading that every ruby method has a return value.

But when I enter the following into irb:

```
def printme(txt)
    print(txt)
end

printme('xyz')
```

the output is:

```
xyz => nil
```

So now I'm confused as to which value printme is returning. Does this method return xyz or nil? And why is the hashrocket there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, every method in Ruby returns a value.

In your example, `xyz` is the output of `printme('xyz')`, but not the return value. The return value is `nil`. If no value is explicitely returned, a method returns the value of its last statement, in this case, the [`print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-print) method returns `nil`.

If you execute the code in irb, it shows the return value after the text `=>`.

Comment: OK, thank you! So the format is something like: `output => return value` (if any)

Comment: Every method has a return value, not every method outputs something.

Comment: @YuHao - I think that the term "output" may be a bit confusing. I would say that `xyz` is not _the output_ of the method, but rather that the method _prints "xyz" to the console_. Since the console also prints the return value of the method, it results in the output line which confused the OP.